# How to use Twilio new Room Rest API instead of Configuration Profile SID?

Tags: rest, twilio

Twilio recently stopped their Configuration Profile SID in favor of the new Room Rest API.

Previously I used to create an access token with the configuration profile SID grant and then pass the access token to javascript to connect the participants:

```
$callerCallId = substr(md5(microtime()), 0, 15);
$callerAccessToken = new Services_Twilio_AccessToken($accountSid, $apiKeySid, $apiKeySecret, 3600, $callerCallId);
$callerConversationGrant = new Services_Twilio_Auth_ConversationsGrant();
$callerConversationGrant->setConfigurationProfileSid($configurationProfileSid);
$callerAccessToken->addGrant($callerConversationGrant);
$callerToken = $callerAccessToken->toJWT();
```

With the new REST API, what do I do? Twilio's official documentation is not helpful at all.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

If you are on the Video Group Rooms private beta, then you should be able to see the [documentation here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video/overview-group-rooms). You actually don't need to change anything about the way you authorize your users, you will still need to generate the JWT from your server and pass it to the client.

The difference is that rather than creating and joining the room from the client, you will want to [use the REST API to create the room](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video/rest-api-rooms#rooms-list-resource) first. Then you can use the room name in the client to join that room.

If you have feedback on the API, the documentation or anything about Group Rooms then please get in contact with the Video team on video-product@twilio.com.